# Listening for mobile(sims) subscription info list

Tags: android, kotlin-flow

Well, i am trying to listen for sim cards in the phone (user insert or remove sim card) by checking the **subscriptioninfolist** in a **viewmodel** using **flows**, i am not sure if this is a viable way of doing this but for some reason it's not working, here is my viewmodel code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val application: Application
):ViewModel() {

private val _subscriptionManager = MutableStateFlow<SubscriptionManager?>(null)
val subscriptionManager: StateFlow<SubscriptionManager?> = _subscriptionManager.asStateFlow()

private val _subscriptionInfoList = MutableStateFlow<List<SubscriptionInfo>>(emptyList())
var subscriptionInfoList: StateFlow<List<SubscriptionInfo>> = _subscriptionInfoList.asStateFlow()

private val _isPermissionGranted = MutableStateFlow(false)
val isPermissionGranted: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isPermissionGranted.asStateFlow()

init {
    getSubscriptionInfoList()
}

fun getSubscriptionInfoList(){
    if (checkSelfPermission(application.applicationContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
        != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        viewModelScope.launch { _isPermissionGranted.emit(false) }
    } else{
        viewModelScope.launch { _isPermissionGranted.emit(true) }
    }
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _subscriptionManager.emit(
            application.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
        )

        subscriptionManager.collect{subscriptionManager ->
            _subscriptionInfoList.emit(subscriptionManager!!.activeSubscriptionInfoList)
            subscriptionInfoList = flow {
                emit(subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList)
            }.stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(500L),
                initialValue = emptyList()
            )
        }
    }
    Log.d("list size:",subscriptionInfoList.value.size.toString())
}
}
```

I collect my flows in my view but if the sim cards are inserted only after launching the app, the app does not react to them, sims don't get added to the **subscriptionInfoList**.